# Post hoc test for an ANCOVA with polynomial term

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, anova, posthoc

I have a model with an interaction term between a polynomial covariate and a factor. I performed an ANCOVA test and the interaction term was significant. Now I want to perform a post hoc test, but I can't figure out how to do that. I want to test if the growing curves of different species differ significantly (I have 3 species).
My model is something like that:

```
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ poly(Petal.Length,2)*Species, data=iris)
```

Comment: You didn't actually tell us what you're interested in testing

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. I edited my question.  I want to test if the growing curves of different species differ significantly (I have 3 species).